# Is there a web redirect method or example using an application gateway using terraform?

Tags: redirect, terraform, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-gateway, azure-app-service-plans

im trying to create a service for web redirect through the application gateway using terraform.

I would like to authenticate the application gateway sl with the free certified (azurm_app_service_managed_certified) of the azure app service plan, is there an example?

Currently, thinking about the composition as follows. However, azurem_application_gateway is demanding ssl certification, so I don't know how to work.

Please let me know if there's a way to solve the problem in that way or in another way.

The problem with the script below is that if you want to use https in the application gateway, you have to use certificate, and I want to make and use free certificated in the service plan.

```
resource "azurerm_application_gateway" "app_gateway" {
  provider = azurerm.generic
    
  name                = "${local.service_name}-app-gateway"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  enable_http2        = true
    
  sku {
     name     = "Standard_Small"
     tier     = "Standard" # v1
     capacity = 2
  }
    
  gateway_ip_configuration {
     name      = "${local.service_name}-ip-config"
     subnet_id = azurerm_subnet.front_subnet.id
  }
    
  frontend_port {
     name = local.frontend_port_name
     port = 80
  }
    
  frontend_port {
     name = local.backend_port_name
     port = 443
  }
    
  frontend_ip_configuration {
     name                 = local.frontend_ip_configuration_name
     public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.pub_ip.id
  }
    
  backend_address_pool {
     name  = "${azurerm_virtual_network.vn.name}-beap"
     fqdns = [local.host_name]
  }
    
  backend_http_settings {
     name                  = local.http_setting_name
     cookie_based_affinity = "Disabled"
     port                  = 443
     protocol              = "Https"
     request_timeout       = 60
     host_name             = local.host_name
  }
    
  http_listener {
     name                           = "${local.listener_name}-http"
     frontend_ip_configuration_name = local.frontend_ip_configuration_name
     frontend_port_name             = local.frontend_port_name
     protocol                       = "Http"
  }
    
  http_listener {
     name                           = "${local.listener_name}-https"
     frontend_ip_configuration_name = local.frontend_ip_configuration_name
     frontend_port_name             = local.backend_port_name
     protocol                       = "Https"
  }
    
  request_routing_rule {
     name                       = "${local.request_routing_rule_name}-http"
     rule_type                  = "Basic"
     http_listener_name         = "${local.listener_name}-http"
     backend_address_pool_name  = local.backend_address_pool_name
     backend_http_settings_name = local.http_setting_name
  }
    
  redirect_configuration {
     name                 = local.redirect_configuration_name
     redirect_type        = "Permanent"
     include_path         = false
     include_query_string = false
     target_listener_name = "${local.listener_name}-https"
  }
    
  request_routing_rule {
     name                        = "${local.request_routing_rule_name}-https"
     rule_type                   = "Basic"
     http_listener_name          = "${local.listener_name}-https"
     redirect_configuration_name = local.redirect_configuration_name
  }
    
  lifecycle {
     ignore_changes = [
       backend_address_pool,
       backend_http_settings,
       frontend_port,
       http_listener,
       request_routing_rule,
       ssl_certificate,
       redirect_configuration
     ]
  }
}

resource "azurerm_dns_zone" "zone" {
   provider = azurerm.generic
    
   for_each            = toset(local.dns_zone_names)
   name                = each.key
   resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
}
    
resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "service_plan" {
   provider = azurerm.generic
    
   name                = "${local.service_name}-service-plan"
   location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
   resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
    
   sku {
     tier = "Basic"
     size = "B1"
   }
}
    
resource "azurerm_app_service" "service" {
   provider = azurerm.generic
    
   name                = "${local.service_name}-service"
   app_service_plan_id = azurerm_app_service_plan.service_plan.id
   location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
   resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
}
    
resource "azurerm_app_service_custom_hostname_binding" "service_host_bind" {
   provider = azurerm.generic
    
   count               = length(local.dns_zone_names)
   hostname            = "${local.dns_zone_names[count.index]}"
   app_service_name    = azurerm_app_service.service.name
   resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
    
   lifecycle {
     ignore_changes = [ssl_state, thumbprint]
   }
    
   depends_on                      = [
     azurerm_app_service.service,
     azurerm_resource_group.rg
   ]
}
    
resource "azurerm_app_service_managed_certificate" "service_manage_cert" {
   provider = azurerm.generic
    
   count                       = length(local.dns_zone_names)
   custom_hostname_binding_id  = azurerm_app_service_custom_hostname_binding.service_host_bind[count.index].id
}
    
resource "azurerm_app_service_certificate_binding" "service_certi_bind" {
   provider = azurerm.generic
    
   count               = length(local.dns_zone_names)
   hostname_binding_id = azurerm_app_service_custom_hostname_binding.service_host_bind[count.index].id
   certificate_id      = azurerm_app_service_managed_certificate.service_manage_cert[count.index].id
    
   ssl_state = "SniEnabled"
}
```

i want a service that simply directs to another website through dns using terraform, and if there is any other way, please let us know. (include http to https)

To protect and prevent website abuse, we would like to redirect multiple domains to one website.
ex : (adomain.net -> [www.target.com](http://www.target.com), adomain.tv -> [www.target.com](http://www.target.com), bdomain.net -> [www.target.com](http://www.target.com))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fist of all there is no support for app services managed certificate with application gateway as of now.

Yes, you can do redirection from multiple domains to one domain using system.webserver rewrite rule either inside **app services web.config** file or application gateway **rewrite rule**.

Comment: Hello, thank you for replay XD

What I'm thinking about now is to get the free certification of the service plan and use it.
Is it possible with a free app certificate?
As far as I know, rewrite supports from v2, but I use v1.
Also, isn't it okay not to use rewrite for redirect?

Comment: Come to think of it, I don't need an http ssl certificate, right?
Since redirect is not required from http to https, what do you think about the service plan authenticating only and http redirecting to the outside?

Comment: Certificates are meant for application and not for the ASP (VM). Redirection is part of System.WebServer and works at application after SSL negotiation successfull over HTTPS protocol.
Service plan is just a hardware and you secure application with certificate deployed on that plan.

Comment: Oh... Yes, you're right.

Doesn't the application gateway currently support http 301 redirection(to an external url)?

Comment: yes, it does support. you need to make use of rewrite rule in app gateway.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/rewrite-url-portal#configure-url-rewrite

Comment: Ok, I will try to change v2 for rewrite. Thank you for replay, I will back finished test